# Find string in array to another string array C#

Tags: arrays, string, find

Give two string arrays I want to find the first occurrence of a string in A1 with A2. I know I can do it "long hand" but could I use Array.Find() or something like that?

Many thanks

Comment: Do you mean an exact occurrence, or as a substring? It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're interested in the intersection, basically. LINQ to the rescue!

```
var firstCommon = a1.Intersect(a2).FirstOrDefault();
```

The documentation for [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) would suggest this will return the items in the order of `a2`:

> When the object returned by this method is enumerated, `Intersect` enumerates *first*, collecting all distinct elements of that sequence. It then enumerates *second*, marking those elements that occur in both sequences. Finally, the marked elements are yielded in the order in which they were collected.

However, this is demonstrably incorrect. It will actually enumerate *second*, and then yield results in the order of *first*... which is what you want here.